# Is elimination of x giving me a new answer of the textbook??

Tags: systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

My textbook has [this system of equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXhWI.png),

$$x-y+5z = 3
\\ 2x+3y-z = 2
\\ -4x-y-9z = -8$$

The answer it lists is $(0, 13/14, 11/14)$. I can get the answer by eliminating $y$ or $z$, but when I eliminate with $x$, I get an infinite solution.

I multiply the first equation by $-2$ and add it with the second equation to get $5y - 11z = -4$. Then I multiply the second equation by $-2$ and add it with the third equation to get $5y - 11z = -4$ too! I did the calculations many times and I'm still confused!! I used all three equations by eliminating $x$ yet still got infinite solution.

Comment: There are infinitely many answers; if $x-y+5z=3$ and $2x+3y-z=2$, then $-2(x-y+5z)-(2+3y-z)=-2\times3-2$, so automatically $-4x-y-9z=-8$

Comment: (FWIW, for better accessibility, link-rot resistance and visibility to search engines, it's preferable to transcribe out the equations rather than link an image. I've submitted an edit to do just that, but it's awaiting approval)

Comment: The system you linked does have infinite solutions.  The solution cited is one of many.  More generally, the set of all solutions can be written as $\{(0,13/14,11/14) \color{red}{+(1,-11/14,-5/14)t}~:~t\in\Bbb R\}$